# doPost method is not getting called when clicked submit in the jsp file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am following the tutorial in this link.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOUDEFVjUXM. I am not using any IDE. Instead of using annotations, I am configuring the `web.xml` file. I am using Tomcat. The files am working with are below.

**LoginServlet.java**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);
  }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    response.getWriter().println("Success");
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <input type="text" name="username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When I enter username and password in the login.jsp page, I am getting [the following error in Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiQ6D.png).

> HTTP Status 404
>   Type: Status report
>   Message: Login
>   Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose htat one exists.

But in the tutorial, the doPost method is getting called. I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have missed to add to your url to your contextPath.
In tomcat contextPath coincides with the name of the project.

replace in your login.jsp `action="/[myProjectName]/login"`

Comment: No, I did. This is the url I used. http://localhost:9090/ServletProject/login. Once I enter username and password, the page got redirected to localhost:9090/login.

Comment: add in action before /login your projectName again -> you must call post to localhost:9090/ServletProject/login
<form method="post" action="ServletProject/login">

Comment: I am sorry. Idid not quite understand what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: when you hit login link leads to localhost:9090/login, but what you need is to lead to  localhost:9090/ServletProject/login. So the problem may be in login.jsp, Try to replace action in form with "ServletProject/login"

Comment: It is not working. This time the error message got changed to "Message /ServletProject/ServletProject/login."Also, in the video tutorial that I am following, at 34:32, the page is getting redirected to localhost:8080/login.

Comment: I am sorry but this must work, can you try with action="/ServletProject/login"